# Tuple Class object takes no values

Tags: python, function, object

I create an instance of class Vector2 with line `AB = Vector2.from_points(A, B)`

But python errors out with `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

on line `AB = Vector2.from_points(A,B)`

and on line `return Vector2(cls, P2[0]-P1[0], P2[1]-P1[1])`

so I figured maybe the book is wrong (I'm looking at examples in a book). I subtract the Vector2 and cls from the def from_points statement so that...

this is how the new line reads: `return (P2[0]-P1[0], P2[1]-P1[1])`

When I do this a receive the vector value from def from_points equal too (5, 10)

But then python errors out on:

`print AB.get_magnitude()`

with `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_magnitude'`

so without the code related to Vector2 and cls the program won't read AB as a class object but it seems that I'm not formatting it right so it won't go through.

I have been stuck on this for days.

```
#Vector Test
import math

class Vector2(object):

def _init_(self, x=0.0,y=0.0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def _str_(self):
    return"(%s,%s)"%(self.x,self.y)

@classmethod
def from_points(cls, P1, P2):
    return Vector2(cls, P2[0]-P1[0],P2[1]-P1[1])

def get_magnitude(self):
    return math.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)

A = (15.0, 20.0)
B = (20.0, 30.0)
AB = Vector2.from_points(A, B)
print AB
print AB.get_magnitude()
```

CHANGED CODE:

```
#Vector Test
import math

class Vector2(object):

def _init_(self, x=0.0,y=0.0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def _str_(self):
    return"(%s,%s)"%(self.x,self.y)

@classmethod
def from_points(cls, P1, P2):
    return (P2[0]-P1[0],P2[1]-P1[1])

def get_magnitude(self):
    return math.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)

A = (15.0, 20.0)
B = (20.0, 30.0)
AB = Vector2.from_points(A, B)
print AB
print AB.get_magnitude()
```

Comment: Vector2 is cls. Use one or the other, not both to construct from points

Comment: Also you need double underscores for \_\_init\_\_ and \_\_str\_\_

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I'll gladly revert it. Good luck with your code! Personally I think it'd be good to work on your indentation.

Comment: Wow i didn't make any sense 6 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's (probably) what you mean.

```
#Vector Test
import math

class Vector2(object):

    def __init__(self, x=0.0,y=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return"(%s,%s)"%(self.x,self.y)

    @classmethod
    def from_points(cls, P1, P2):
        return Vector2(P2.x-P1.x,P2.y-P1.y)

    def get_magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)

A = Vector2(15.0, 20.0)
B = Vector2(20.0, 30.0)
AB = Vector2.from_points(A, B)
print( AB )
print( AB.get_magnitude() )
```